# Convert nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have table with values

```
report nvarchar(max) not null
description nvarchar(max)
```

In stored procedure I want select values from table and then convert it to varbinary max. I seletct :

```
select 
    CONVERT(varbinary(max), [report]) as [report], 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(varbinary(max), [description]), '') as [description]
from myTbl
```

but I get an error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: And have you done what the error message suggests? For reference: [`CONVERT` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: ISNULL(CONVERT(varbinary(max),[description]),$0). $0 instead of ''.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The failure is occurring because you convert description to `varbinary`, but then try to cast any null values back to a `varchar`.  You just need to move `ISNULL` inside the `CONVERT` or change the conversion value when null to a binary value.

### ISNULL in CONVERT

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), report), 
    CONVERT(varbinary(max), ISNULL([description], '')) as [description]
FROM myTbl
```

### Proper ISNULL Value

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), report), 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(varbinary(max), [description]), 0x) as [description]
FROM myTbl
```

Both versions will produce the same output `0x` if description is null.